# Context menu Items missing

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I have an operating System Vista(64-Bit).
I have made a dll.For example, i have installed "folder protect". due to this dll when i right click on any folder the "folder protect" appears in the context menu.Actually any software being installed appears in the context menu.But sometimes it 
appears and sometimes not.on the other hand in windows xp, there is no such problem.

So Where is the Issue?

Kindly provide the solution as soon as possible.

Comment: This actually sounds more programing related.

Answer (score 0):

You may have built a 32-bit library.  I suspect 32-bit shell extensions do not play very well with 64-bit operating systems like your own.
Your WinXP system is very likely 32-bit.